# Get Razor to not recognize @ symbol every time

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

So when putting an @ symbol into a javascript portion of an MVC Code such as

```
$("#filter").tweet({
count: @Model.Tweets,
filter: function(t){ return ! /^@\w+/.test(t["tweet_raw_text"]},
username: '@Model.TwitUser'
});
```

how do you get around the system thinking that is Razor and the beginning of a code block in the filter: function line?

Comment: Just curious! Where did you placed this JS?

Comment: I put the JS in the view of my MVC...

Comment: @stuartd I don't agree that it's a duplicate, he's trying to set JavaScript variables with values from Razor.

Comment: Does no one read these questions? Almost everyone is giving an answer about the escape @ character in razor. He is trying to set his JavaScript values using his Model in Razor.

Comment: This shouldn't have been closed, it got closed when I was answering it try using a generic method when setting your javaScript values e.g. count: @(Model.Tweets),

Comment: Creating a small sample project with his code, it works perfectly fine when you escape the @ symbol in the regular expression, IMO its a duplicate.

Comment: Was my answer helpul? If so, accept it so others can use it as well. If it wasn't, did you find a different solution to your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the `@:` syntax for mixing text and Razor variables

```
$("#filter").tweet(@:{
  count: @Model.Tweets,
  filter: function(t){ return ! /^@\w+/.test(t["tweet_raw_text"]},
  username: '@Model.TwitUser'
});
```

You may have to play around with the placement of the `@:` to get it to work, but it should get you the results you're looking for. There are more syntax tips here: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I assume your JS code is embedded in your view, if then what i usually do is to declare properties on page load and then use them in JS

In View:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var urlProfile = '@Url.Action("Index", "Profile")';</script>
```

In my JS separate file:

$("#cancel-step").click(function () {
    window.location.href = urlProfile;
});

Comment: can i use my razor code for the count and username if i have the code in an embedded file?

Answer (score 0):

Escape it using

```
@@
```

Or try

```
@:
```

Or put the problematic part in

```
<text></text>
```

Comment: i tried this and it actually gave me an error for the
    <text></text>